# MVC3 Javascript doesn't work off page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

This isn't really a critical problem, I just don't understand why it doesn't work. I am using mvc3 for a web app, and I have a global.js script that I include in the _Layout header. It runs just fine.

I have a single page that has a lot more JS on it, so I don't want to include it all in the global file. The problem is, the javascript only works when it is on the page, at the bottom, in script tags. If I put the JS in its own file and use a script src tag, either on the page or in _Layout, the JS doesn't run. It shows up in the source though.

I have even tried moving pieces. If a function or handler is moved from the page to its own file, that piece wont work. Unmoved sections continue to run.

No changes to the code. If I just pull it off the page, put it in its own file, and link to it, the code no longer works. Both register functions with $(document).ready(function ()). Are two scripts not allowed to do this? The only other thing I can think of is that body pages (rendered from _Layout's @RenderBody()) cant link to scripts.

Comment: you can certainly have more then one document ready handler in a page.

Comment: Don't just accept an answer to keep your rate high! That rate is such a useless metric, hold out for a *correct* response. Marking responses that do not solve your problem as *accepted* does not help the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you referencing those external js files? You should use URL helpers to ensure proper paths to them:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now inside this external `myscript.js`, depending on whether you referenced it in the `<head>` section or at the end before the closing `</body>` you should use `$(document).ready` or not.

What you could do is define a `scripts` section in the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
    ...
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>        
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
```

which could be used by each view to include its specific scripts:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

and finally inside `myscript.js` you can directly manipulate the DOM without wrapping in `document.ready`:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert('submitting a form');
});
```

You could include as many external scripts as you like (although you should reduce their number to a strict minimum to avoid additional HTTP connections as per [YSlow recommendations](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html))

Comment: I had not seen that rendersection/scripts thing before, I will give that a try. Why not put it in the document.ready though?

Comment: This did not work either. I tried both pasting the same js, and removing the document ready and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just assume that you have a typo mistake in your javascript. Try to load the page with Firebug or Chrome and see the log for errors;

Comment: If there was a typo, then it would not work when it is still on the page, but it does. I am not re-typing the whole thing, I cut and paste. It works in one place, and not another.